Without Codacy's `Remark-lint` triggering `[no-undefined-references]` `[no-shortcut-reference-link]` notices, how to use Markdown footnotes?
Found https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint/issues/234, which just says that for local installs of Remark-lint you can update .remarkrc to allow use of Pandoc syntax ([^<number>]) footnotes.
But the problem is with hosted Remark-lint (through cloud tools, such as GitHub's Codacy scan tool, which does not offer .remarkrc for you, just .github/workflows/codacy.yml).
Or is there some other form of footnotes which Remark-lint allows (just not Pandoc footnotes)?
List of Remark-lint errors is at https://github.com/SwuduSusuwu/SubStack/runs/34401539110, the exact commit which triggered this is https://github.com/SwuduSusuwu/SubStack/commit/188d87fdc2b1496238f4e792a003cb328c3f423f
https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-lint/issues/234 says that Pandoc block footnotes should not trigger no-undefined-references, so perhaps over the last 4 years this has regressed (got worse)?
https://github.blog/changelog/2021-09-30-footnotes-now-supported-in-markdown-fields/ just shows the Pandoc[^1] syntax for footnotes (which Remark-lint's default rules flag). Is there some other syntax (which does not trigger those notices from Remark-lint?)
[^1]:
This is an example which ends with a _Pandoc_ reference to a footnote. [^2]

[^2]: This is the _Pandoc_ footnote.

example Remark-lint notices:
Annotations

Check notice on line 1 in Markdown.md

Code scanning / Remark-lint (reported by Codacy)

Warn when references to undefined definitions are found.

Note
[no-undefined-references] Found reference to undefined definition
Show more details

Check notice on line 1 in Markdown.md

Code scanning / Remark-lint (reported by Codacy)

Warn when shortcut reference links are used.

Note
[no-shortcut-reference-link] Use the trailing [] on reference links
Show more details

(if you click "Show more details" it shows the lines from your Markdown which have footnotes).

GitHub allows you to "Dismiss", but it still says that the commit (which introduced footnotes, and all commits which follow) failed. Codacy solution: must disable? Is Codacy malicious?
